# How to correctly implement (and maybe better organize) this JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html

Pretty new to JavaScript and I could use a hand here. I have in my webpage a user review form. It is a row with 10 drop down boxes that allows the user to answer the questions about a student on a rating scale of 1-5. If the user selects < 2 for any of them, they are prompted with a text box to explain the low rating(call it LowRatingPopUp). There is a button that adds another student to review. When the button is clicked, a new review form is added on the fly (call it NewStudent).

The problem I am having is with printing/displaying the new form. In NewStudent function I am concatenating the form as a large string in the function to re-print everything.It therefore is not correctly creating a new LowRatingPopUp when the button is pressed. The code can't be included or it breaks the page.  It also make for a HUGE amount of code to be in Function-2.

Default HTML Section:

```
        <section>
            <!-- Form -->
            <form method="post" action="#">
                <div class="row uniform">
                    <!-- Break -->
                    <div class="12u$">
                        <h3>Please use the following scale when rating the student:</h3>
                        <ul style="list-style: none" ;>
                            <li>1 = Poor</li>
                            <li>2 = Less than acceptable</li>
                            <li>3 = Satisfactory</li>
                            <li>4 = Very good</li>
                            <li>5 = Excellent</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div style="height:550px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;">,<!-- container for reviews-->
                            <div id="ReviewForm">
                                <hr>
                                <h2>
                            Student:
                            <select>
                               <option value="Adam">Adam</option>
                               <option value="Bob">Bob</option>
                               <option value="Corey">Corey</option>
                            </select>
                         </h2>
                                <div class="table-wrapper" ; text-align: center;>
                                    <table>
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Motivation and general attitude</th>
                                                <th>Educational initiative & Scholarship</th>
                                                <th>Understanding of course material</th>
                                                <th>Ability to apply course material</th>
                                                <th>Oral English expression skills</th>
                                                <th>Written English expression skills</th>
                                                <th>Ability to analyze/integrate/apply</th>
                                                <th>Ethical standards & integrity</th>
                                                <th>Respect for diversity</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select>
                                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select>
                                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select>
                                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select>
                                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select>
                                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select>
                                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select>
                                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select>
                                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select>
                                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <div id="Other" class="showother" style="display:none" name="textbox" id="textbox" type="text">
                                            </div>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <div style='display:none;' id='business'>
                                        <input type='text' class='text' name='business' placeholder="You gave a rating of less than 3 in one or more categories. Please provide a brief explination as to why." /><!--LowRatingPopUp-->
                                        <br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
            <input type="hidden" name="count" value="1" />
            <div class="control-group" id="fields">
                <label class="control-label" for="field1"></label>
                <div class="controls" id="profs">
                    <form class="input-group-btn">
                        <div>
                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="ReviewForm();">Add another student</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

JS Function when button is clicked:

```
function ReviewForm() {
    room++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('ReviewForm')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass" + room);
    var rdiv = 'removeclass' + room;
    divtest.innerHTML = '<hr>' +
        '<h2>Student:</h2>' +
        '<select>' +
        '<option value="Adam">Adam</option>     ' +
        '<option value="Bob">Bob</option>       ' +
        '<option value="Corey">Corey</option>' +
        '</select></h2>' +

        '<div class="table-wrapper">' +
        '<table>' +
        '<thead>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<th>Motivation/general attitude</th>' +
        '<th>Educational initiative & Scholarship</th>' +
        '<th>Understanding of course material</th>' +
        '<th>Ability to apply course material</th>' +
        '<th>Oral English expression skills</th>' +
        '<th>Written English expression skills</th>' +
        '<th>Ability to analyze/integrate/apply</th>' +
        '<th>Ethical standards & integrity</th>' +
        '<th>Respect for diversity</th>' +

        '</tr>' +
        '</thead>' +
        '<tbody>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<select>' +
        '  <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>' +
        ' <option value="1">1</option>' +
        '<option value="2">2</option>' +
        '    <option value="3">3</option>' +
        '    <option value="4">4</option>' +
        '    <option value="5">5</option>' +
        ' </select>' +
        '   </td>' +                                                                
        '<td>' +
        '<select>' +
        '  <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>' +
        ' <option value="1">1</option>' +
        '<option value="2">2</option>' +
        '    <option value="3">3</option>' +
        '    <option value="4">4</option>' +
        '    <option value="5">5</option>' +
        ' </select>' +
        '   </td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<select>' +
        '  <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>' +
        ' <option value="1">1</option>' +
        '<option value="2">2</option>' +
        '    <option value="3">3</option>' +
        '    <option value="4">4</option>' +
        '    <option value="5">5</option>' +
        ' </select>' +
        '   </td>' +

        '<td>' +
        '<select>' +
        '  <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>' +
        ' <option value="1">1</option>' +
        '<option value="2">2</option>' +
        '    <option value="3">3</option>' +
        '    <option value="4">4</option>' +
        '    <option value="5">5</option>' +
        ' </select>' +
        '   </td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<select>' +
        '  <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>' +
        ' <option value="1">1</option>' +
        '<option value="2">2</option>' +
        '    <option value="3">3</option>' +
        '    <option value="4">4</option>' +
        '    <option value="5">5</option>' +
        ' </select>' +
        '   </td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<select>' +
        '  <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>' +
        ' <option value="1">1</option>' +
        '<option value="2">2</option>' +
        '    <option value="3">3</option>' +
        '    <option value="4">4</option>' +
        '    <option value="5">5</option>' +
        ' </select>' +
        '   </td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<select>' +
        '  <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>' +
        ' <option value="1">1</option>' +
        '<option value="2">2</option>' +
        '    <option value="3">3</option>' +
        '    <option value="4">4</option>' +
        '    <option value="5">5</option>' +
        ' </select>' +
        '   </td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<select>' +
        '  <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>' +
        ' <option value="1">1</option>' +
        '<option value="2">2</option>' +
        '    <option value="3">3</option>' +
        '    <option value="4">4</option>' +
        '    <option value="5">5</option>' +
        ' </select>' +
        '   </td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<select>' +
        '  <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>' +
        ' <option value="1">1</option>' +
        '<option value="2">2</option>' +
        '    <option value="3">3</option>' +
        '    <option value="4">4</option>' +
        '    <option value="5">5</option>' +
        ' </select>' +
        '   </td>' +

        '                   </tr>' +
        '               </tbody>' +
        '               <tfoot>' +
        '               </tfoot>' +
        '           </table>' +
        //If I add the next chunk of code to the function, it breaks the functionality of the JS on the page
        /* '<div style='display:none;' id='business'>'+
         '<input type='text' class='text' name='business' placeholder="You gave a rating of less than 3 in one or more categories. Please provide a brief explination as to why." />'+
        '<br/>'+
        '</div>'+*/ 
        '</div>'
    objTo.appendChild(divtest)
}
```

Comment: This may not directly answer your question, but you might really love VueJS.  Specifically the conditions and loops section. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Conditionals-and-Loops Otherwise, you might consider splitting this big function into smaller reusable functions that return string outputs that represent the pieces you want

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you can use the template strings (backtick) for construct and concatenate large and multiline strings:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings

```js
var name = 'Mike';
var inner = `   <div>         \
 <h2> hello ${name} </h2>     \
 </div> `;


console.log(inner);
```

Comment: Nothing shows up when I click "Run code snippet." Does Stack Snippets support ES6 features?

Comment: You can see in the console of the browser (F12)

Answer (score 0):

You can make functions that just check each form item using the onChange element and then have independent js functions display hidden text areas if certain options are selected. Here is an example of what I'm talking about.

```js
function typeCheck(that){
  if (that.value == "data"){
    document.getElementById("ifdata").style.display = "inherit";
    document.getElementById("ifvoice").style.display = "none";
  }
  else if (that.value == "voice"){
    document.getElementById("ifdata").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifvoice").style.display = "inherit";
  }
  else if (that.value == "full"){
    document.getElementById("ifdata").style.display = "inherit";
    document.getElementById("ifvoice").style.display = "inherit";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("ifdata").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ifvoice").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="type" name="type" cols="4" onchange="typeCheck(this);">
  <option value=""></option>
    <option value="voice">Voice</option>
    <option value="data">Data</option>
    <option value="full">Full</option>
</select>

<div id="ifdata" style="display: none;">
  <label for="CID">Circuit ID(s):</label>
  <textarea id="CID" name="CID" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="ifvoice" style="display: none;">
  <label for="TN">Telephone Number(s):</label>
  <textarea id="TN" name="TN" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
```

Disclaimer: this solution is using style.display = 'none'; which does not work on Safari. Safari requires that you position the element at the top of the page.

For my use case Safari compatibility was not needed, so the implementation that works on all other browsers was used.

Comment: This is exactly what the hard coded section of my page does. When I select a certain value from my drop down menu, the text box appears just fine. It is when I run the function to create a new form I am having trouble with.

Comment: For the second section of my form on submit I just had a js function load a whole new page to the user, so instead of having the js generate a whole new form by manipulating the dom of an existing page, just have it present the user a new page that follows the same template with the new form items. If that doesn't work for your use case, then unfortunately I don't know if I have the whole answer for you.